# React Component not shown when using conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a React JS example from CodeSchool. I have been able to follow the examples. The problem is when I try to implement an IF conditional to pass different data to a Component. The component not shown is the 'Comment'. Look inside the `_getComments` function. If I use an If conditional, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joelgb/vxtkpzog/15/, to decide which array will be passed, the code will not work. But if I simply put the below code without any `If` the Component Comment is rendered correctly.

```
const commentsList = [
      {id: 1, author: "author1", body: "body1"},
      {id: 2, author: "author2", body: "body2"},
      {id: 3, author: "author3", body: "body3"}
    ];
```

Note that using this approach, it won't work.

```
var commentsList;
    if (a=='a'){
     commentsList = [
      {id: 1, author: "author1", body: "body1"},
      {id: 2, author: "author2", body: "body2"},
      {id: 3, author: "author3", body: "body3"}
    ];
  }
  else
  {
     commentsList = [
      {id: 1, author: "author4", body: "body4"},
      {id: 2, author: "author5", body: "body5"},
      {id: 3, author: "author6", body: "body6"}
    ];      
  }
```

Can anyone point me towards the error?

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(commentsList));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, you forgot to call `comments()`

This

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component{
    render() {
      const comments = this._getComments.bind(this,'a');
      return (
        <div>
            <h3>Comments</h3>
             {comments}  // <--- You are not calling comments
            <button onClick={this._getComments.bind(this,'b')}>north</button>
        </div>           
      );
    }
    ...
}
```

should be

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component{
    render() {
      const comments = this._getComments.bind(this,'a');
      return (
        <div>
            <h3>Comments</h3>
             {comments()}
            <button onClick={this._getComments.bind(this,'b')}>north</button>
        </div>           
      );
    }
    ...
}
```

[your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxtkpzog/20/)

[A better solution using `state`](https://jsfiddle.net/vxtkpzog/24/)

Comment: I forgot using state. Thanks a lot, it works flawless.